# How to format toLocaleDateString([$MyDateTimeColumn]) to return YYYY-MM-DD?

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-list

I have JSON formatted a column with the following:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
    "elmType": "a",
    "txtContent": "*****",
    "attributes": {
    "target": "_blank",
    "href": "='https://*****.sharepoint.com/sites/group-*****/Lists/*****%20*****/AllItems.aspx?FilterField1=Person&FilterValue1=' + [$Author.title] + '&FilterField2=My_x0020_DateColumn&FilterValue2=' + toLocaleDateString([$Start])"
    }
}
```

It outputs a link to another list that is filtered on a Person and Date column.

The link creation works correctly, however the date from `toLocaleDateString()` is output as:

```
21/12/2020
```

whereas it needs to be:

```
2020-12-21
```

or perhaps even:

```
2020-12-21&FilterDisplay2=21%2F12%2F2020
```

for the filter to be applied correctly (even though the value in the column is actually displayed as `21/12/20`).

How can I output the date value as `YYYY-MM-DD` so that the filter is applied correctly?

**Edit**

Have implemented @Jerry_MSFT 's solution as follows - for some reason it is returning month as `11` rather than `12` (does `getMonth()` return a 0 indexed value? or is something weird happening?):

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
    "elmType": "a",
    "txtContent": "*****",
    "attributes": {
    "target": "_blank",
    "href": "='https://*****.sharepoint.com/sites/group-*****/Lists/*****%20*****/AllItems.aspx?FilterField1=Person&FilterValue1=' + [$Author.title] + '&FilterField2=My_x0020_DateColumn&FilterValue2=' + getYear([$Start])+'-'+getMonth([$Start])+'-'+getDate([$Start])"
    }
}
```

**Edit 2**

Month does seem to be 0 indexed, this seems to work:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
    "elmType": "a",
    "txtContent": "*****",
    "attributes": {
    "target": "_blank",
    "href": "='https://*****.sharepoint.com/sites/group-*****/Lists/*****%20*****/AllItems.aspx?FilterField1=Person&FilterValue1=' + [$Author.title] + '&FilterField2=My_x0020_DateColumn&FilterValue2=' + getYear([$Start]) + '-' + (getMonth([$Start])+1) + '-' + getDate([$Start])"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per my test and search, it seems the `toLocaleDateString()` cannot convert date format. We can do it manually with an expression like this:

```
=getYear(@currentField)+'-'+(getMonth(@currentField)+1)+'-'+getDate(@currentField)
```

Just as OP mentioned, the getMonth returns a 0-based value, we need to add 1 for it.

> getMonth: returns the month in the specified date according to local
> time, as a zero-based value (where zero indicates the first month of
> the year). - Only available in SharePoint Online

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have added my attempt of implementation to original post.  Month is being returned as `11` rather than `12` - does `getMonth()` return 0 indexed value? (edit:  looks like it does, so need to know how to add, not concatenate, 1 to the value returned by `getMonth()`)

Comment: Update:  Have added solution to OP.

Comment: @user1063287, yes it is a zero-based value so we need to add 1 for it. I updated the answer, please check. =getYear(@currentField)+'-'+(getMonth(@currentField)+1)+'-'+getDate(@currentField) works in my end.